# "What/When is the best time to callback?"

Tags: meaning, idioms, conversation

Which is better? I want to know the difference.

> - What is the best time to callback?
> - When is the best time to callback?

Answer (score 3):

Either, but I'm more concerned about *callback*. I can see no reason for making it one word.

Comment: I can see a reason for *not* making *callback* a single word - in this context, it's simply incorrect.

Comment: The word callback exists as a noun in programming, but I do not support verbing it.

Comment: yeah my mistake, thank you though for correcting. I just want to know which is more convenient to use. When or what?

Comment: @post: There really isn't any significant difference. You'll find about the same number of written instances in Google Books for both *"What"* and *"When is the best time to..."*. And that's still the case if you change **is** to **'s**, showing that neither is any more or less "formal" than the other. Not every different choice of words has significance.

Comment: This is based on opinion. There are no sources to back up your claiim

Answer (score 0):

Either will be understood, but "What is the best time to call back?" is more commonly used.

At a technical level, using "what" is modeling the answer as a generalized conceptual entity, while using "when" is specifically modeling it as a chronological time.  Nobody is ever thinking about this distinction when using either phrase, however.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that *what* is more common. Do you have a source? I would use "when" if asking about a time. I might say "What time is best to call back?" But using the OP's sentence, I'd say "When is the best time to call back?"

Comment: -1 because I'm feeling a bit tetchy today. I find no evidence in Google Books to suggest that either *what* or *when* more often precedes *is the best time to...*. They are pretty much equal in terms of meaning, prevalence, and "degree of formality", so I dispute your statement about *"is more commonly used"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Try Google Web Search.  37.2MM vs. 29.8MM.

Comment: @chaos: Sorry, but I think Google's *"About nnnn results"* there are "guesstimates", which reflect nothing more than the fact that *"what"* is more common on the Net than *"when"* (by a factor of 4:3). In Google Books, ["what's/when's the best time to](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%27s+the+best+time+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) both give about 6.5K results, which I think means any "preference" is marginal, to say the least.